# i want to create a class from fields of dynamic form so that i can create corresponding table in sqlite dynamically

Tags: java, android, sqlite, reflection

i want to create a class from fields of dynamic form so that i can create corresponding table in sqlite dynamically.

i an generating the form based on xml file. after i capture data i want to save those data into sqlite database. But since i am not sure what fields will be there in form, i can't create database. so i thought of creating database dynamically based on form fields but for that i need a class having the form fields as data which will be passed to the method which will create the table.

Comment: confused, you want to create class or table with fields depending on data you get..

Comment: i am also confused actually

Answer (score 0):

here is advice, create the database before touching to any anything else along with the table with possible column you might require and keep default value to null. that way you have to only update the data in table you get from the form.

You would have to come up with a way to recognizing which columns to update, this looks cumbersome but will help you if you plan on updating your app or even while making changes